# Making Gutenberg blocks with two pre-existing blocks

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to make a *Gutenberg block* in WordPress that can take in custom HTML and display just like the block that already exists. I have the frame of the block created but I cannot figure out how to call the existing custom HTML block inside the one I am creating.
Is this possible or do I need to hard code it myself?

Comment: Up. I hope someone will answer this question.